# Using oval border-radius in a SASS mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

```
//Usage
@include border-radius(150px / 70px); 

//Mixin
@mixin border-radius($values) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $values;
  -moz-border-radius: $values;
  border-radius: $values;
}
```

The result would be:

```
border-radius: the division of 150/70, which is 2.xxxxx-something
```

How can this be fixed within the same mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation here:

```
.foo {
  @include border-radius(#{150px} / 70px);
}
```

Comment: I'm giving you the correct answer. However I went with `@include border-radius("150px / 70px");` and then I used `unquote` inside the mixin :)